# Rails params[:id] keeps returning the same id

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm working on Add to favourites functionality, where a user clicks on a link and adds a resource to his favs, and clicks again in order to remove it. The problem is that no matter what I do with my code Rails keep favouriting anything but the question I am actually looking for

**Disclaimer: in my code I misspelled the *favorite* word, please forgive me**

```
Controller

class FavoritesController < ApplicationController  
  def favor
    @question = Question.find_by(params[:id])
    @favorite = Favorite.new

    @favorite.user = current_user
    @favorite.question = @question

    @favorite.save

    redirect_to :back
  end

  def unfavor
    @question = Question.find_by(params[:id])

    @favorite = current_user.favorites.find_by(question_id: @question)
    @favorite.destroy
    redirect_to :back
  end
end
```

routes

```
concern :favoriteable do
  post 'favorites/favor',   to:   'favorites#favor',    as: :favor
  post 'favorites/unfavor', to:   'favorites#unfavor',  as: :unfavor
end

resources :questions, concerns: [:commentable, :favoriteable] do
  resources :answers
end
```

question#show

```
span 
  - if current_user.favorites.exists?(question_id: @question)
    = link_to 'Unfav this', question_unfavor_path(@question), method: :post
  - else    
    = link_to 'Fav this', question_favor_path(@question), method: :post
```

Log (**note how 33 becomes 15**)

```
Started POST "/questions/33/favorites/favor" for 127.0.0.1 at 2014-07-01 19:10:02 +0400
Processing by FavoritesController#favor as HTML
  Parameters: {"authenticity_token"=>"SjOLDdIx4DMfHwLJLBdNd6N12tLNyN+QdaMT0OlpOCU=", "question_id"=>"33"}
  Question Load (0.7ms)  SELECT  "questions".* FROM "questions"  LIMIT 1
  User Load (0.1ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users"  WHERE "users"."id" = $1 LIMIT 1  [["id", 11]]
   (0.1ms)  BEGIN
  SQL (0.3ms)  INSERT INTO "favorites" ("created_at", "question_id", "updated_at", "user_id") VALUES ($1, $2, $3, $4) RETURNING "id"  [["created_at", "2014-07-01 15:10:02.490036"], ["question_id", 15], ["updated_at", "2014-07-01 15:10:02.490036"], ["user_id", 11]]
   (1.0ms)  COMMIT
Redirected to http://localhost:3000/questions/33
```

Can't figure it out, please help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`find_by` is used with attributes like `Question.find_by(id: params[:id])`. You are using it incorrectly i.e., without specifying the attribute name.

When you do

```
@question = Question.find_by(params[:id]) ## in "favor" and "unfavor" actions
```

it is equivalent of doing

```
@question = Question.find_by(nil)
```

Reason for `nil`: Notice the `params` hash generated in the server log, you are receiving `params[:question_id]` and NOT `params[:id]`. So, `params[:id]` is `nil`.

Hence, the query formed is something like:

```
SELECT  "questions".* FROM "questions" LIMIT 1
```

which most probably returns the first record in `questions` table. This is the reason why you are getting the same question record with `id = 15`.

To resolve this, you need to update both `favor` and `unfavor` actions with:

```
@question = Question.find(params[:question_id]) ## Using "find" which searches a record based on "id" attribute
```

-OR-

```
@question = Question.find_by(id: params[:question_id]) ## Using "find_by" and specifying "id" attribute
```

I would suggest you to use the first option i.e., `find` as its more semantic way of getting the result when you are searching based on `id`(primary key)

Answer (score 2):

Your parameters are posting `:question_id` not `:id`

Either switch to this in your view

```
- if current_user.favorites.exists?(question_id: @question)
    = link_to 'Unfav this', question_unfavor_path(id: @question.id), method: :post
- else    
    = link_to 'Fav this', question_favor_path(id: @question.id), method: :post
```

Or switch to this in your controller (this is in my mind cleaner)

```
@question = Question.find(params[:question_id])
```